# Multithread imbalance Java

Tags: java, multithreading

This is the code for my thread test.

```
class TestThread extends Thread {   
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Run thread "+this.getId());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the main function, I set up 100 threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    TestThread tt = new TestThread();
    tt.run();
}
```

And this is the result I got

```
Run thread 8
Run thread 8
Run thread 8
Run thread 8
...
```

Why only thread 8 printed out? It seems that this is the only thread that is running. How can I make other threads work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.run` will call the threads run-method directly. It will be executed synchronously, not parallel.

To run a thread asynchronously, use `Thread.start()`.

By the way: Extending `Thread` and starting the thread-objects directly is not recommended. It is usually far better to implement your tasks as a [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and then use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to implement multithreading.

Answer (score 3):

to start a thread. use `start()` method instead of `run()`.

what you're doing now is basically running that function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling thread. start instead of thread.run.